# Inline block confirm messages

Tags: 7, forms, emails

I have a contact (web)form in my sidebar on my site and I would like to display a custom confirm message when a users submits the form. However, this message should replace the contact form.

I've tried with [Inline Messages](http://drupal.org/project/inline_messages) or with the form-settings (no-redirect), but every solutions just redirects the entire website to the node and displays the message inline. So, that not what I want, obviously...

So, is there a solution where the content of the page remains unchanged, but when submitting the form in the sidebar, only the sidebar refreshes and shows the confirmation message?

Comment: You could also use a modal dialog to show the message (see [Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools)).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option... I need the message to be ìn the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Webform Ajax](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax) module will give you the functionality you describe. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... adds AJAX support to [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) (3.0 and above).
>
> As a first step it focusses to simply add form AJAX paging and submit. Form submissions get ajaxified including prev/next pages. Especially for multipage forms, this leads to faster loading (less data transfer), better usability and finally smaller server load.